# Link to redirect previous page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm using a script for image hosting.
Each image generates a dynamic address, for example:

- image 1 = www.site.com/img-52786ffebed6d.html
- image 2 =  www.site.com/img-529035bbc3c9e.html

When a user visits an image for the first time, it redirected to www.site.com/first_visit.php page.

In "first_visit.php" has a link "Back to the image".
How do I make the link to return to image?

I've tried

```
<?php
if (isset ($ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
header ('Location:'. $ _SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']);
Else {}
  header ('Location: index.php');
}
exit;
>
```

works but is instant, I need it on the link "Back to the image" and do not know how

Comment: Why you use extra space in php tag `<? php` instead of `<?php` and closing tag should be `?>`

Comment: sorry, my bad on copy-paste, but is not that

Comment: Okay that's good. I just cross check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.history.back(-1);return false;">Back</a>
```

Comment: Just hope that they do not click on the home button or some other bookmark in between.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the first request for the image redirect to `/first_visit.php?return_to=52786ffebed6d`, so that you know where to send the user back to.

Comment: That would be a solution, but which code use to generate each link? Each image is a different link and there are thousands of them..

Comment: You'd just pull the unique URL out of the query string. It's being passed in via `return_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the location of the first page as a parameter - which will get appended to the url `www.site.com/first_visit.php`

you will ned up with something like `www.site.com/first_visit.php?backto=www.site.com/img-52786ffebed6d.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  echo '<a href="'. urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) . '">Back</a>';
else {
  echo '<a href="index.php">Back</a>';
}
```

Use link tag instead of redirecting. Better if it wrapped with proper HTML code.